lastpage package error: hyperref version too old
I am getting the following error in my code:
! Package lastpage Error: hyperref package version too old.
See the lastpage package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.405 \end{document}

References are not getting reflected in the pdf (bib file).
I am using the template for Journal of Optical Communication and Networking added with some other packages.
\documentclass[9pt,twocolumn,twoside]{osajnl}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\journal{jocn} 

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
 This is introduction 


\section{References} 
\bibliography(references_bib}
\end{document} 



The most likely cause of this problem is that your hyperref package version is too old... so the solution would be to update the package. How did you install LaTeX, on which operating system, which LaTeX distribution, when did you install it, did you perform updates at some point?

Seems you've updated/installed package lastpage without updating the rest of the TeX distribution. With MiKTeX this can easily happen if you use a package the first time on a not updated MiKTeX. Note: In case of a multi-user MiKTeX installation you need to do the update in Admin-Mode and in User-Mode, both using MiKTeX Console.

@cabohah I have updated all the packages from MiKTeX and it works fine now. Thank you so much!
